# If the electron have spin 1 , how many electrons would be required to fill 1s orbital?

Tags: particle-physics, electrons, atomic-physics, quantum-spin

How many electrons can be filled in 1s orbital, if electron have spin 1 instead of 1/2.

Comment: If electrons were spin-1 they would no longer be fermions and no longer obey the exclusion principle. At least as I understand it you would in theory be able to put as many electrons there as you wanted to. Changing the spin of the electron may have other effects owing to QFT that prevent it being in a bound state with the nucleus altogether although I do not know.

Comment: if i understand this correctly the physical meaning of a 1/2 and -1/2 spin are that one is against the magnetic field(high energy state) and the other is in the same direction of the external magnetic field. Thus we have diamagnetism when there are 2 electrons in lone pair (cancel each other out) and paramagnetism when there is only 1 free electron

Answer (score 1):

> How many electrons can be filled in 1s orbital, if electron have spin 1 instead of 1/2.

Physics is a discipline which  observes and measures the behavior of nature and uses mathematical modeling in order to be able to describe existing data, and predict future behavior.

The models have extra axioms, to the mathematical ones, imposed, called: postulates, principles, laws . These  extracted from the study of data, and are imposed on the mathematical model , so as to choose the solutions that describe the existing data .

So, electrons have axiomatically spin 1/2 , obey the Pauli exclusion principle/axiom and only two of them can fit at a given line, which fits the data exactly, and explains new observation very well.

A particle with negative charge and the mass of the electron and spin 1  would fit the mathematical model , and a large number of them could fit in the mathematical 1s orbital as bosons do not obey the Pauli exclusion principle. The levels would change, because a different potential exists between , (for example in a hydrogen type solution), four charge -1 and a proton. A great number would have such a potential well that finally the definition of 1s will not have a meaning. The answer is: there will be only an energy and kinematic limit to such an imaginary state.

The fact is that none such states have been observed,  and bound atoms exist only between fermions, hence the [standard model.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model)

Comment: short and precise